# Where can I find comprehensive documentation on Google Test?

Tags: googletest

A Google search yields the GitHub page for Google Test. I'm finding many links around the web to https://github.com/google/googletest, which now redirects to the GitHub page. The GitHub project has an overview and a readme.md, which mostly explains how to build Google Test.

Where is the official user documentation for Google Test, or some equally useful, comprehensive documentation?

Comment: https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/primer.md

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The documentation is in the GitHub repo, as .md files in the googletest/docs directory. Start with [Primer.md](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/docs/primer.md). And then you can look at more [advanced](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/docs/advanced.md) topics.

Answer (score 10):

Shameless plug: Because it's annoying to go through the unrendered md files locally and use the difficult to navigate around md files on github, I publish the google test docs (https://gunslingerfry.github.io/google-test-docs) using [mkdocs](https://www.mkdocs.org/) with a very minimal addition of an index.